# Trigger snakemake rule-execution upon reference db update

Tags: snakemake

I want to trigger a snakemake rule (essentially a BLAST call) whenever my reference DB (a moderatly-sized fasta file) is updated.

- When I pull the latest version of the DB, would snakemake execute the "BLAST" rule, e.g. due to a newer time stamp of the reference file?

What about if I want to see if there is a relevant change in the DB in the first place? So I would first put the reference DB under git version control and make a git diff and execute only if the git diff is non-zero.

- How would Snakemake trigger a rule based on a git diff?

Answer (score 0):

Snakemake relies on the time stamp for triggering. You can ignore the timestamp by marking a file as ancient (see docs). Then, you can figure out whether you want to update or not and trigger the rule manually via the -R flag. Alternatively you can use a remote provider to download the DB. I guess if the modification date changes on the server, there will also always be a change in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a custom "freshness" check which is not essentially just comparing timestamps, you will need to implement your own input file modifier abstraction. `temp()`, and `ancient()` are two examples of modifiers. @johannes-köster also hints at remote files. Those are also good examples which rely on the timestamps provided as part of response headers (e.g. reported by the http server).

Another possibility is to do it in two steps. You would mark your database reference as `ancient()` to let snakemake ignore the timestamps, and specify an additional input file whose timestamp you control with a script. In a first step, you run a custom script to query the database state, and if the database state has changed, you simply `touch` your special file to update its timestamp. The second step would be to run the snakefile as normal.

Example: `is_newer`

https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/src/9a4bb3fc84a8302a080bd7c0c37749b45f8e538a/snakemake/io.py#lines-294

In the case where the file is a remote object, it will use the implementation of the remote provider. (you might have to implement your own custom).